# Error parsing attribute on @page directive

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to set a custom property "**DisableBrowserCache**" on the page directive  like so

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"  DisableBrowserCache="True"
 CodeFile="Info-services.aspx.vb" Inherits="Manager_Info_services" %>
```

This is the inheritance chain

```
Partial Class Manager_Info_services
Inherits EltApp.ELTPage
'Code
End Class


Namespace EltApp
Public Class ELTPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Property DisableBrowserCache() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _DisableBrowserCache
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _DisableBrowserCache = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class End Namespace
```

As you can see I inherit from a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page. This issue is that setting the property on the directive gives me the following error

```
System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005):
    Error parsing attribute 'disablebrowsercache': 
    Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not have a public property named 'disablebrowsercache'. 
---> system.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): 
    Error parsing attribute 'disablebrowsercache':
    Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not have a public property named 'disablebrowsercache'.
---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005):
    Error parsing attribute 'disablebrowsercache':
    Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not have a public property named 'disablebrowsercache'.
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessError(String message)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateControlParser.ProcessUnknownMainDirectiveAttribute(String filter, String attribName, String value)
```

I have a feeling it's because im not directly inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page in the codebehind file.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way the Page directive works. You're asking it to understand your derived class even before the page is parsed.

You should put this in the `Page_Init()` event of `Manager_Info_services`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i've been doing. Is there any article at hand that i can read to better understand the page directive? Btw, Thank you for your answer.